# Closed form for finite summation of sequence $\sum^n_{i=1}{e^i/i}$

Tags: summation

Does there exist a closed form for finite summation of the sequence  $\sum^n_{i=1}{e^i/i}$ ?

Comment: Yes it does. Is that a homework problem?

Comment: I think it is fair to say that there is no reasonably elementary closed form for this value.

Comment: Considering that even harmonic numbers have no known simple elementary closed form despite of hundreds of years of intense inspection, I can hardly expect that it would do so.

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative of the function $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{x^i}{i}$ which is easier to compute.

Comment: Uh? No matter what $\,n\,$ is chosen?!

Comment: @DonAntonio I think $e=0$, right.

Comment: You are right, I edit.

Comment: And how do you integrate the result?

Comment: I still can't see how that sum is "easier" to compute...perhaps an integral, though...?

Comment: Yep, by this way you obtain a closed formula given by the integral of a fraction.

Comment: @Don: He didn't say that sum is easier to compute. He said the derivative of that sum is easier to compute.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^nx^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k=\frac{1-x^{n-1}}{1-x}$$

Integrate indefinitely the above:

$$\int f(x)\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^n\int x^{k-1}dx=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k}{k}\ldots$$

Comment: How do you extract the result from the integral?

Comment: Integrate the RHS of the first line wrt $\,x\,$ ...

Comment: An formula involving an integral isn't really much more of a closed form than a formula involving a summation.

Comment: Well @Hurkyl, that may depend on the OP, but I'd agree with you in general. Anyway that's an option for him...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I understand the underlying idea, but what integration limits do you use? (Or are you integrating in $\mathbb{C}$?)

Comment: None @copper.hat: indefinite integral, unless the OP adds some more conditions, of course.

Comment: Then I don't understand, presumably $e = \exp(1)$?

Comment: @copper: Indefintie integrals don't have limits; the method described just says to antidifferentiate. You use a known value ($x=0$) to fix the constant afterwards. The plug in $x=e$ if you want the value of the sum at $x=e$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Like I say, I understand the basic idea. The details seem a little more complicated...

Answer (score -1):

Maple writes it as $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{{\rm e}^i}{i} = -\Phi \left( {{\rm e}},1,n \right)\; {{\rm e}^{n}}-\ln 
 \left( -{{\rm e}}+1 \right) +{\frac {{{\rm e}^{n}}}{n}}$$

where $\Phi$ is the Lerch Phi function.

Comment: Lerch at $(z,s,n)$ with $s=1$ and $|z|\gt1$... Are you sure that this simply exists? Probably related: the argument of the logarithm on the RHS is real negative?

Comment: Defined using analytic continuation.

Comment: You mean, the logarithm on the RHS? But surely you realize that the LHS is purely real?

Comment: Yes, I do realize that.  So what? A real number can be written as the sum of non-real complex numbers.

Comment: Sure but then one should explain the determination of the logarithm one is using. Another problem is to define $\Phi(z,s,a)$ when $|z|\gt1$, and this probably involves another choice of cut set. As long as you say nothing about these two points, I am afraid this answer is not very useful.

Comment: Once you choose a branch of log, you use the corresponding branch of $\Phi$ that makes $\Phi(z,1,n) z^n + \ln(1-z)$ real when $z$ is a positive real.  So if you use the principal branch of log, the branch cut for $\Phi$ is on the real axis from $1$ to $+\infty$.
This does seem to be the choice Maple makes.